# Checking for usename in mysql ...If it exist then inserting into other table Otherwise the base table

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, mysql-workbench

Well i have the following table Table1 in MySQL workbench--

```
user_id       int            not null,autoincrement
movie _id     int            not null 
movie_name    varchar        
user_name     varchar
rating        int
genre         varchar
```

Now following is the insertion into database--

```
try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:XXXX/Recommendation1", "root",
                    "XXXXXXXXXXX");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            int i = st
                    .executeUpdate("insert into Table1(movie_Id,movie_name,user_name,rating,genre) values('"
                            + movieId
                            + "','"
                            + mname
                            + "','"
                            + pname
                            + "','" + ratingr + "','" + genre + "')");
            out.println("Data is successfully inserted!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print(e);
```

Now what i want that,if there already exist a user_name with that value (pnmae),which i am entering it should not enter into my Table 1 or update,but it should enter into another table Table 2,The schema of table 2 is as following--

```
movie _id     int            not null 
movie_name    varchar        
user_name     varchar
genre         varchar
```

For that what to use .How to use if -else condition

The following is what i am doing while checking for the username if it exists

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:XXXX/Recommendation1", "root",
                    "wXXXXX");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            //Statement st2 = con.createStatement();
            String SQL = "SELECT * from Table1 WHERE user_name ='" + pname
                    + "' ";
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(SQL);

            --if (rs.) {   //What to put here

                int j = st
                        .executeUpdate("insert into Table2(movie_Id,movie_name,user_name,genre) values('"
                                + movieId
                                + "','"
                                + mname
                                + "','"
                                + pname
                                + "','" + genre + "') ");

            }

            int i = st
                    .executeUpdate("insert into Table1(movie_Id,movie_name,user_name,rating,genre) values('"
                            + movieId
                            + "','"
                            + mname
                            + "','"
                            + pname
                            + "','" + ratingr + "','" + genre + "') ");

            /*  ResultSet rs = st1.executeQuery();
                out.println("name is already there");
                out.println("Data is successfully inserted!"); */

        /*  final String Query = "SELECT t1.user_Id from Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2 on t2.movie_Id = t1.movie_id WHERE t2.user_name = 'vishal'";

            PreparedStatement st11 = con.prepareStatement(Query);
            ResultSet rw = st11.executeQuery();
            rw.last();

            int id = rw.getInt("user_Id");

            System.out.print("ID: " + id);*/
```

Thanks

Comment: Do a SELECT for pname before INSERT and only INSERT if no rows returned. Isnt it?

Comment: Hey Manish doing that only like checking whether username exist if it does not then inserting into table 1 otherwise into table but i am not getting how

Comment: try rs.next() in IF condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :-

```
        boolean isUser=false;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:XXXX/Recommendation1", "root",
                "wXXXXX");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();           
        String SQL = "SELECT 1 from Table1 WHERE user_name ='"+ pname
                + "' ";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(SQL);
        isUser=rs.next();
        Statement st2 = con.createStatement();
        if (isUser) {   //check the user is exist or not

            int j = st2.executeUpdate("insert into Table2(movie_Id,movie_name,user_name,genre) values('"
                            + movieId
                            + "','"
                            + mname
                            + "','"
                            + pname
                            + "','" + genre + "') ");

     }else{

     int i = st2.executeUpdate("insert into Table1(movie_Id,movie_name,user_name,rating,genre) values('"
                        + movieId
                        + "','"
                        + mname
                        + "','"
                        + pname
                        + "','" + ratingr + "','" + genre + "') ");

       }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi Jdeveloper Thanks ............but not getting desired output.Both the enteries are getting populated in Table 1 and nothing is going in table 2...........................

Comment: Thanks JDeveloper....Works like Butter....But one thing can you explain.............SELECT 1 from Table1 WHERE user_name ='"+ pname
                + "' ";  What is this selection like'1' is that the user_Id only?? .............    Thanks

Comment: 1 means , it will only display 1 (nothing else) if user id and password matches. No need to display * (means all record which use more time and resources).